# Setting an long click event for calendar

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a calendar that shows a popup window when i long press the calendarview. But nothing happens when i do long click the calendarview. I tried using other event listeners like `on click,onhover`,etc. But none of them respond. I even thought of trying to use the calendarview as a dialog but none of the listeners i found in android documentation for dialog look for a long clock.

This is what i have tried to do.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

PopupWindow p;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CalendarView c=(CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
    c.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            openpopupwindow();
            return true;
        }

        private void openpopupwindow() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater)MainActivity.this.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View lay=inflator.inflate(R.layout.add_appointment, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.popupagenda));
            p=new PopupWindow(lay,300,300,true);
            p.showAtLocation(lay, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            Button badd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
            badd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    p.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: try replacing lay in showAtLocation with the parent layout id..see if that helps

Comment: CalenderView is a mixture of several other views. That have their own event handling. So the top most view of CalenderView won't get the event at all.

Comment: @NightCrawler didnt work

Comment: @brummfondel is there any other way to handle the calendarview events then other than use of buttons